# Unity strange clones behavior

Tags: unity, grid, console

I am setting up a grid of tiles (2d sprites) in Unity with this code:

```
public class Grid : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject slot;
public int gridW = 9;
public int gridH = 9;

private GameObject [,] grid = new GameObject[9, 9]; 

void Awake(){

    for(int y=0; y<gridW; y++)
    {
        for(int x=0; x<gridH; x++)
        {
            GameObject gridSlot = (GameObject)Instantiate(slot, new Vector3(x, y, 0), Quaternion.identity);
            gridSlot.transform.parent = transform;
            grid[x,y]=gridSlot;
        }
    }

}
```

I then would like to have printed on the console the x,y coordinates of an individual tile when clicked on it. This is the script attached to the tile prefab:

```
public class Tile : MonoBehaviour {

void Start () {


}

void Update () {

    if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        Debug.Log(transform.position.x + " " + transform.position.y);
}
```

Yet when I click on a tile I get printed the coordinates for ALL of the tiles on the grid. Why is this happening? Is there something very basic I am missing...?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Yet when I click on a tile I get printed the coordinates for ALL of
>   the tiles on the grid. Why is this happening? Is there something very
>   basic I am missing...?

It appears as though you are spawning one `Tile` for every tile on your map. So an 8x8 map would have 64 `Tile` instances. Every instance is `Update`'d by the Unity runtime. When the mouse is down, every instance checks if `Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)` is true, and when it is, prints its own position.

So every time you click, every tile prints its position.

You probably want to *either* check if the clicked position is actually within the bounds of the tile (the simplest-possible-solution) or have something else at a higher level, possible the map object, handle the mouse click, determine which tile was clicked, and tell that specific tile to do whatever needs to be done in response to a click.

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDown.html works if your tiles have colliders. Though, I'd use some kind of global method and get rid of the colliders.

Comment: So Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) is not specific to the single script that calls it but it's a 'global' event? Am I understanding this correctly? @Byte56 what kind of global method are you thinking of..? Thanks guys!!!

Comment: `GetMouseButtonDown` is triggered when an object's collider is clicked, specific to the object the script is attached to. A global event would be a single script that detects clicks, determines where they are in relation to your tiles, then alters the tile at that location. About as specific as I can get in a comment.

Comment: I think there's a typo in @Byte56's comment above. The description there applies to the `OnMouseDown` message, not the method `Input.GetMouseButtonDown`. The latter simply asks "is the mouse button pressed?" with no context about what scene objects are under the pointer.

Comment: Yes, @DMGregory is correct

Comment: Ok got it! Managed to make it work as planned with OnMouseDown.... Thanks for the help guys!